# Laravel 5.3 get request value in route file web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Im trying to access request in web.php file but cant find a function to call. Request is passed automatically to all controller functions but I want to perform action common for all routes so I wanted to do it in route/web.php file that is new route file in Laravel 5.3.

i tried

```
$request = Route::getCurrentRequest();
```

but it returns null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) global helper in `web.php`

```
dd(request());
```

Comment: Thank you, I did this and its not null, it has request structure, but its not filled out at this point. All values are null or strange. Im looking to access cookie. Is it possible in web.php?

Comment: If you don't see some data in request object, then it's not available at this point. I wonder why do you want to get cookie in `web.php`? Maybe there is a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I set user preferred language in cookie. I want to get that cookie and call App::setLocale(request()->cookie('lang')); before request is routed. I managed to setLocale for each route in every controller, but I want to do it in one place because its same for all routes.

Comment: I guess it's better to use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) for this.

Comment: I tried with middleware and in the handle function the request cookies are still not set.

Comment: Finally when I placed my middleware at the end of middlewareGroups web array in Kernel.php - it worked.